# Uploading recorded audio to the node js server using Multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, multer, mediarecorder-api

I want to upload the recorded audio file to the Node js server using multer But I am not getting the file on the server. Here is my code .What should I do ?

JS CLIENT SIDE CODE :

```
mediaRecorder.onstop=(e)=>{
          let blob=new Blob(chunks,{'type':'audio/mp3;'});
          chunks=[];
          let audioURL=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          audio.src=audioURL;
          var data = new FormData();
          var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
          data.append('file',blob,'audio.mp3');
          request.open('post','/upload'); 
          request.send(data);
          console.log('File sent');
        }
```

SERVER SIDE CODE :

```
app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), function (req, res, next) {

          console.log(req.file); 
          var oldpath = req.file;
          var newpath = __dirname;
          fs.readFile(oldpath, function (err, data) {
          fs.writeFile(newpath, data, function (err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                res.end();
            });

  })
})
```

And I am getting this error now :
[See the output Here and Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0vg6.png)

Comment: @iambatman Thanks ,But I tried this, its not working

Comment: You should set the content type header in xmlhttp request

Comment: Here is it ` request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");`

Answer (score 1):

Set the content type header in http request

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
data.append('sound',audioURL);
```

Comment: I am getting this error Error: Multipart: Boundary not found

Comment: Try my answer again

Comment: Can you share the content type header from the network tab in here?? and also check the request body properly included the file

Answer (score 0):

```
mediaRecorder.onstop=(e)=>{
      let blob=new Blob(chunks,{'type':'audio/mp3;'});
      chunks=[];
      let audioURL=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      audio.src=audioURL;
      var data = new FormData();
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      data.append('file',blob);
      request.open('post','/upload'); 
      request.send(data);
      console.log('File sent');
    }
```

[image]

this will work

Comment: Getting this : MulterError: Unexpected field